# How to make the 'wheel' event fire once per scroll?

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks, addeventlistener

I'm trying to write some React code that detects if a user is scrolling up or down and then increments or decrements a state depending on the direction. I'm using the 'wheel' event because I have a 1 viewport sized page that has the 'overflow: hidden' property on it, so there's no where to actually scroll. Instead, I detect the page to show based on the state mentioned earlier.

Here's what I have so far, but this fires multiple times per scroll instead of just once:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleTrackpadSwipe = (event) => {
      if (event.deltaY > 0) {
        console.log('swiped down')
        setTrackpadSwipe('swiped down');
        if(pageNumber < 4 ) {
          setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);
        }
        setTrackpadSwipe('none');
      }
      else if (event.deltaY < 0) {
        console.log('swiped up')
        setTrackpadSwipe('swiped up');
        if(pageNumber > 1) {
          setPageNumber(pageNumber - 1);
        }
        setTrackpadSwipe('none');
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('wheel', handleTrackpadSwipe);
    
  }, [trackpadSwipe, pageNumber]);
```

Comment: "Don't confuse the wheel event with the scroll event. The default action of a wheel event is implementation-specific, and doesn't necessarily dispatch a scroll event. Even when it does, the delta* values in the wheel event don't necessarily reflect the content's scrolling direction. Therefore, do not rely on the wheel event's delta* properties to get the scrolling direction. Instead, detect value changes of scrollLeft and scrollTop of the target in the scroll event."

Comment: Right that makes sense, but how can I detect value changes in scrollLeft and scrollTop if my page doesn't physically scroll because it's only 1 screen viewport in size and has 'overflow: hidden' on it? Doesn't that mean that scrolling is disabled?

Comment: I made a similar thing, it was not easy and the result was not perfect. I set `position:sticky` for the content and had a second div having smaller z-index and having height = number of pages * viewport height.

Comment: Scroll event fires multiple times when the user scrolls once. You need to use a technic called debouncing to overcome this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/